# TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'55

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below code will not join, when debugged the command does not store the whole path but just gives the error TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

```
try:
    appdata = os.path.expandvars("%AppData%")
    config = import_cfg('config', os.path.join[appdata, 'identities', 'sun'])
    config_loaded = True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
config = import_cfg('config', os.path.join[appdata, 'identities', 'sun'])
```

Functions are not called using square brackets. Try parentheses.

```
config = import_cfg('config', os.path.join(appdata, 'identities', 'sun'))
```